# When I try to acess my websitefolder in Ubuntu Im getting a blank page

Tags: 14.04, server, permissions, php, websites

I recently installed Ubuntu and I'm a php developer. And I'm trying to use Ubuntu for this purpose.

I already installed `mysql-server` and `phpmyadmin` and I can already access the `localhost`. And also If I create some file and write for example `echo 'hello';`, I'm getting this `echo` when I access the document that I create.

But I'm trying to access a folder of a website that I developed in windows, and first gave me an error about permissions I changed the permissions, but now I still have problems, when I try to access my website folder I get a blank page.

Do you know why this can be happening?

Comment: a blank page in php means you still have some error. please turn on display errors like that : ini_set('display_errors', 1); and you will see your mistakes

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in windows everything is working fine. So I think I dont have php errors...

Comment: Could you add a screen-shot/ or your code(index.php), and `/etc/hosts` also, `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Install**

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-client mysql-server php5 phpmyadmin libapache2-mod-php5
```

<sup>You will be asked to input a password by mysql. Make one up.</sup>

---

**Configuration**

Edit `/etc/hosts`

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Add

```
127.0.0.2     Yourwebsitename
```

Edit `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

then add the following:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/YourWebsiteFolderName/
   ServerName Yourwebsitename
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer blade, but wheere I need to add the <virtualHost...><.../>? In apache2.conf but where?

Comment: @Marby All the way at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your answer blade. It seems that is working. But I need to do this: "sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/website. But now Im with other problem with my .htaccess file. It is being ignored by ubuntu or something :s

Comment: @Marby, this is another question :) post it and someone will give you an answer for sure. You should read apache documentation, here is a useful [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html) to start, and where you can find what you need.

Comment: @blade19899 I don't recommend adding editing `apache2.conf`, it's better to create a virtual host file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. Almost all apache configurations can be overridden without any need to modify the default conf.

Comment: I added the `libapache2-mod-php5` package as it is needed for apache to run PHP

Answer (score 0):

See the apache log for details. Open a terminal, then use the following commands, one for the error log, one for the apache log. The -F option makes that it keeps the log open and checks for new entries. So you can test and keep this open, and will see errors popping up.

```
tail -F /var/log/apache2/error.log
tail -F /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

Depending on your apache setup, the logs may have another location or name.